# Type family not reducing with GHC

Tags: haskell, types

I'm working with type level Nats and I want to reduce a ratio to its simplest terms:

```
import GHC.TypeLits
import GHC.TypeLits.Extra

data TC (n::Nat) (d::Nat) = TC Int Int deriving Show

type family Norm (n::Nat) (d::Nat) ::(Nat, Nat) where
    Norm n d = '(Div n (GCD n d), Div d (GCD n d))

norm  :: Norm n d ~ '(np dp) => TC n d -> TC np dp
norm (a,b) = TC (div a (gcd a b)) (div b (gcd a b))
```

If I have two different terms:

```
a = TC 1 2 :: TC 1 2
b = TC 2 3 :: TC 2 3
```

Then:

```
norm a :: TC 1 2

norm b :: TC 
    (GHC.TypeNats.Div 2 (GHC.TypeLits.Extra.GCD 2 3)) 
    (GHC.TypeNats.Div 3 (GHC.TypeLits.Extra.GCD 2 3))
```

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463874/why-wont-ghc-reduce-my-type-family), however in my case type checking doesn't force it to reduce:

```
norm (TC 2 3 :: TC 2 3) :: TC 2 3
```

fails with:

```
* Couldn't match type `GHC.TypeNats.Div
                         3 (GHC.TypeLits.Extra.GCD 2 3)'
                 with `3'
```

Comment: Does your file have `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Extra.Solver #-}` at the top

Comment: `Norm n d ~ '(np dp)` should be `Norm n d ~ '(np, dp)` I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have forgotten enabling the plugin. The following compiles:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Extra.Solver #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import GHC.TypeLits.Extra

data TC (n::Nat) (d::Nat) = TC Int Int deriving (Eq, Show)

type family Norm (n::Nat) (d::Nat) ::(Nat, Nat) where
    Norm n d = '(Div n (GCD n d), Div d (GCD n d))

norm  :: Norm n d ~ '(np, dp) => TC n d -> TC np dp
norm (TC a b) = TC (div a (gcd a b)) (div b (gcd a b))

a = TC 1 2 :: TC 1 2
b = TC 2 3 :: TC 2 3

b' = norm (TC 2 3 :: TC 2 3) :: TC 2 3
```